# Comparing posted dates in a Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I'm pretty new to Rails, so please be gentle!

I'm currently building an app where I need to do something different if an edit is made without changing a particular field (in this case the date field). On the edit page I've got the original date (called `olddate`) in a hidden field like so:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :olddate, @inspection.date %>
```

When the edit is POSTed in my controller, I want to check if `olddate` is the same as `date` (which is posted via a `date_select`), and if they are different, carry out an action. I've tried this:

```
if @inspection.date != params[:olddate]
  # Do Stuff
end
```

but it seems that as `date` is posted via `date_select`, the date is split into three variables (`date(3i)`, `date(2i)` and `date(1i)`). How do I join these together to check whether they are the same as `olddate`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse out the date manually:

```
olddate = Date::civil(params["date(1i)"], params["date(2i)"], params["date(3i)"])
if @inspection.date != olddate
  # ...
```

Comment: Hmmmmm... I've tried that, and I get `undefined method '<' for nil:NilClass`, so, after a bit of searching round, I added `.to_i` to the params, and now I get `invalid date`. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, what are the params that are submitted?

Comment: Here's the full dump `{... snip
 "date(3i)"=>"6",
 "date(2i)"=>"2",
 "date(1i)"=>"2012",
 ...}`